# Injectivity of the $\alpha$-genus

Tags: differential-topology, spin-geometry, index-theory

My question regards the map defined in Atiyah,Bott,Shapiro "Clifford modules", which equals the index of the Clifford-linear Dirac operator: $$\alpha:\Omega^\mathrm{Spin}_\ast(M)\longrightarrow KO^{-n}.$$ Is $\alpha$ injective in dimension $n\equiv 0,1,2,4\mod 8$ (otherwise it's the 0 map)? I think this is true up to dimension $n=8$ by direct check on the generators, what about $n\geq 9$?

Comment: This fails already in dimension 8. The quaternionic projective plane generates an infinite cyclic summand in $\Omega_8^{\operatorname{spin}}$ whose $\alpha$-invariant is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

No. See for example the work of Anderson, Brown, and Peterson

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183527786